# To check the method used to solve integral calculus problem..

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the following
$ \int\frac{1}{x^2+k}\,\mathrm{d}x$ when $k<0$

so, here is what i've done:
I changed the denominator to $x^2-(\sqrt k)^2$ where $k>0$, so that i can easily apply the formula to solve the type $ \int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

so my question is, is this modification in $k$ correct (or legal in math sense) to solve these type of integrals ? if not then can you please explain whats wrong?

Comment: substitute directly $k=-a^2$ thats correct

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct: you should transform into $x^2-(\sqrt{-k})^2$ or, which is the same,
$$
x^2-(\sqrt{|k|})^2
$$
It's much simpler to set $-k=a^2$. Then you can decompose
$$
\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{p}{x-a}+\frac{q}{x+a}
$$
(partial fractions). The condition is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
p+q=0\\[4px]
ap-aq=1
\end{cases}
$$
After this the integration is elementary.

Comment: I understand your point but I'm still confused both looks same to me. What is the difference?!

Comment: @bhupen If $k<0$ you can’t do $\sqrt{k}$, can you?

Comment: but again it may sound dumb but if you solve $-k=a^2$ we again have value of a as $\sqrt-k$

Comment: @bhupen Can you see the difference between $\sqrt{-k}$ (existing if $k<0$) and $\sqrt{k}$ (not existing if $k<0$)?

Comment: now I see it thank you very much ☺️